# Ring-Clojure/Ring-Json Cannot Open Input Stream

Tags: clojure, ring, compojure

I'm using ring-json. In defining my app, I'm doing this:

```
  (wrap-json-params)
  (wrap-json-body)
  (wrap-json-response)
```

and in my routes, I have this:

```
  (POST "/messages" {params :params session :session} (process-message params session))
```

where the process-message function doesn't do anything but println right now.  When I post json data to the route, I'm seeing the data in an error, but can't figure out why I'm getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot open <{"var1" "hey", "var2" "ho"}> as an InputStream.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Did you set application/json as the content-type on the request?

Comment: This is in my request header: "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have both wrap-json-params and wrap-json-body, **wrap-json-params** is an alternative to wrap-json-body , try removing wrap-json-param!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't know why I was getting the error, but things work properly when I use ring-middleware-format instead of ring-json.